# How to determine whether a feature contains discrete or continuous data in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am wondering is there a way to determine whether a feature (a vector) contains discrete or continuous data?

like feature1 = [red, blue, green] 
feature2 = [1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8]

How can I judge feautre1 is discrete and feature2 is continuous?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Does continuous just mean has decimal places to you? Or can you just check if it's a number?

Comment: What makes `feature1 = [red, blue, green]` discrete? Do you mean `feature1 = ['red', 'blue', 'green']`?  Also, what do you mean by continuous?  `1.1` is a discrete value, as is every other number in a computer, so perhaps you mean integer-valued.

Answer (score 1):

You basically check how many distinct values are in your variable of interest. If the number of distinct values is below a percentage threshold of the number if instances then you can treat the variable as categorical. The percentage threshold depends on the number of instances you have. For example, if you have 100 instances and set a threshold of 5%, then if these instances take below 5 distinct values it is possible to treat the variable as categorical. If you have 1,000,000 instances

Check out this answer from cross validated.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12273/how-to-test-if-my-data-is-discrete-or-continuous

Note that this answer refers to R but the same principles apply to any programming environment and it should not be hard to translate this to matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Every data represented in a computer is discrete, but this is probably not the answer you are looking for.

What stands the value for? Feature 1 seems to be discrete because it describes some names for colours out of a finite set. But as soon as any mixture is allowed (e.g. `"23%red_42%blue_0.11%green_34.89%white"` this becomes a really strange description of a continuous artefact.

Feature 2: no idea, some arbitrary numbers without any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: `class(feature)`, where `feature` is any object, tells you the class name of the object. For example:

```
feature1 = {'red','blue', 'green'};
feature2 = [1.1 1.2 1.5 1.8]

>> class(feature1)
ans =
cell

>> class(feature1{1})
ans =
char

>> class(feature2)
ans =
double

>> class(feature2(1))
ans =
double
```